# sublime text 2 on linux mint

Tags: linux, sublimetext2

I have started using sublime text 2 on linux mint. It is installed under

~/.config/sublime-text-2/

There is a Packages folder in this directory. I downloaded the zip file for the Package Control and unzipped in the Packages directory. Now I can install new packages using the install command. But I don't know where these packages are being installed. I cannot use the newly installed packages. Also I don't see them under ~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using Linux Mint and can tell you that it stores everything in ~/.Sublime Text 2.

Also I would use the copy-paste the code snippet on the [Package Control](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/package_control/installation) website to get Package Control up and running. I've never tried the method your describing for installing Package Control as the copy-paste method has always worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, Package Control folder under `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages`.

If you are root, it will be `/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages`, but when you is user, it will be `/home/[user_name]/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages`.

So, by other way:

1. open your Sublime
2. open `Preferences > Package Settings > Package Control > Settings - User`
3. And see the path in Sublime title or `Ctrl + O`